# JavaScript function is not working. indexOf is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, splice

```
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {   let newArr = [];
```

> Loops through every element of the nested array.

```
for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){     
    for (let j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
```

> If the value on the iteration is equal to the argument passed, it is supposed to set a variable x to be equal to the value of the nested array during the ongoing iteration

```
  if (arr[i][j]==elem){ 
    let x = indexOf(arr[i][j]);
```

> It is supposed to remove the element with index equal to the variable x.

```
    arr[i][j].splice(x,1);
```

> Then it is supposed to push the remained of the nested array to the new array and then subsequently return the new array.

```
      newArr[i].push(...arr[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(newArr);
  return newArr;
}
```

**HOWEVER THERE IS AN ERROR THAT SAYS 'indexOf is not defined'**

I don't understand why it doesn't work. It return indexOf as undefined for every iteration. Please take a look at comments.
Please share your opinion on my code if you don't mind.

Comment: `indexOf` is an array method. You need to call it on an array. See example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf But you already have in the indexes `i` & `j` so it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: indexOf signature is. `array.indexOf()` [see the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` is an `array/string` method and can be called on an array like `array.indexOf(element)`. In your case your you need to pass the `array`.

Also you may skip the `indexOf` because here variable `i` and `j` will give the relevant index of the parent and nested array